# Why doesn't gradle tasks show group or description when using exec?

Tags: android, shell, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My Gradle task stopped showing the `group` and `description` in `./gradlew tasks`, since I've added an `exec {}` in the root `build.gradle`.

**What's going on, and how do I get it back?**

```
task doSomething << {
    group 'yourGroupName'
    description 'Runs your bash script'
    exec {
        workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
    }
}
```

Everything else works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot configure group and description in a `doLast()` closure

this code

```
task doSomething << {
    exec {
        workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
    }
}
```

is the same than

```
task doSomething {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

In the following `group` and `description` are not taking into account

```
task doSomething {
    doLast {
        group 'yourGroupName'
        description 'Runs your bash script'
        exec {
            workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

But here it does :

```
task doSomething {
    group 'yourGroupName'
    description 'Runs your bash script'

    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeez, these Gradle'isms... That did it.